How to get better seal on a 5/8" dishwasher drain line adapter?
I have a kitchen sink drain that has a y-branch for dishwasher drain water. I think the y-branch is 5/8" diameter. This is probably the one I have:
https://www.homedepot.com/p/Oatey-1-1-2-in-x-12-in-22-Gauge-Brass-Hi-Line-Sink-Drain-Tailpiece-Extension-Tube-with-Nominal-Sweat-Branch-HDC813B-3/316622018#overlay
I want to hook up a reverse osmosis drain adapter to it, and the only ones I can find end in a 7/8" diameter (because I think they want to hook into a garbage disposal, which I guess usually have a 7/8" opening).
I've bought two adapters to step down the 7/8" RO end to the y-branch 5/8" end. When I tighten the worm screws, I never get a good enough seal on the 5/8" end, and it leaks.
This is one of the step-down adapters I bought as an example:
https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08172WTYJ?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title
Any ideas on how I can get a better seal? I can install a drain saddle but hoping to avoid drilling into the drain pipe to install that.
Thank you

You're doing something wrong but without accurate information it's hard to guess what.  maybe add photos.

Try a 1 1/2" tailpiece with a true 7/8 branch Like a Poly tail piece.
You may need to install a drain tailpiece and then the tail with adapter into that. It's an extra piece, but that will correct your issue.

The size of the Y branch is the same as nominal 1/2" copper water tube ("pipe"). Solder on a reducing coupling (1/2"x3/4") and you will have a 7/8" OD tip on the Y branch that will fit your hose.
